# stop direct access to page php and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, security, redirect

Guys I need to prevent that users can call up web pages directly from the address bar eg: `www.site.com/page.php`, this should not be allowed.

I have tried various ways, but I also block all calls ajax menu, basically when I log straight on the page I must return to the login page cancellandomi also the session, while it should work when calling the page from jQuery inside the menu.

How can I fix?

Comment: So you're trying to do this:

When the user navigates to that page you redirect them to login page? Or just prevent them from accessing that area?

Comment: You could use `define("test", true)` on the page you want to put your jquery on and then `if(defined("test")){//code}else{die();}` on the page.php

Comment: If the user writes the name from the address bar to the page to be taken to the login page, but if you access the page using the appropriate menu must be able to access (use jquery to call pages). Ideas on how to do it? thanks

Comment: Okay, I no longer understand what you mean. Can you give try to give an example of what you're trying?

Comment: You could make your jQuery Ajax posts (not get) and then block all calls which do not have posted data.

Comment: apologize for my English :(, then, I have a menu that works with JQuery, I want the pages to be accessed only from the menu of the site, the user should not be able to'd take the name of the page eg. Invoice.php and call it directly from the address bar of the web browser . okay? :D

Comment: So in your jQuery function, set a cookie, then read it in your server-side code, if it exists delete it and all is ok, if not redirect to login.

Comment: You could use something like `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])` but there are flaws with it

Comment: some snippet of code to better understand how to do?

Comment: So if It's an AJAX call display the page, If It's not then don't display it? Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a link from your menu - the page attribute contains the name of the page you are linking to:

```
<a page="page1.php">Page1</a>
```

Your client script:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var page=$(this).attr('page');
    setCookie('page', page); // <== you need to write a cookie setting function for this
    location.href = page;
}
```

Then in your php for the target page, read the cookie and compare with the page name.
If it's correct ok, if not redirect to your login page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways:

- Allow or deny by IP with http server config: [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html), [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html)
- Allow or deny by IP in your php script. Example:

  ```
  if (!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
  '192.168.0.1',
  '192.168.0.2'
  // ....
  ))) die ('You are not allowed to run this script');
  ```
- Allow or deny access to page by session flags.
- Use HTTP Authentication : [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html), [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html)